# Stenography- What are the limits?

Tags: limits, data-hiding

I'm working on a steno project and I managed to hide a text, image, sound file inside a cover image file. 
However, I was wondering if I could do a combination of the three, ending with 9 files, each with hidden data in them.

However, I'm running into issues with the text file. I know on the cmd line you can do:
notepad new.txt:pass
and this will allow you to effectively hide a text within a text, but does this could as steno?

Also- is it possible to hide jpeg/mp3 in text?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear (I don't know what you mean, in context, by "hiding a text in a text"). You can hide any file in a literal text file is all sorts of ways, including sophisticated algorithms which use formal grammars to produce output which superficially makes sense. Whether or not you can do so in a way that doesn't look suspicious is of course a different question. Such algorithms expand files sizes, and a drivel-filled text files of several megabytes is sure to look suspicious.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in this way: when I use vecna (a steno tool), it uses the extra bits to hide data on them. So I can hide a text in an image. But there's the issue with text, is there enough bits on it to hide things in?

Comment: Just google "text-based steganography" -- there is a fairly large literature on it. Chapters 6 and 7 in the book "Disappearing Cryptography" has a fairly readable introduction to grammar-based mimicry. It isn't very good for hiding large amounts of information because the resulting files would be too large (and would also look suspicious, defeating the purpose of steganography).

Comment: Thanks, I got some info on it.